# Concatenate Pandas DataFrames with Multiindex columns and irregular timestamps

Tags: python, pandas, time-series, concatenation, multi-index

I have a lot of separate dataframes in a list that each have Multiindexed columns and are a timeseries for different time periods and lengths. I would like to do three things:

1. Bring together all of the separate dataframes
2. Any dataframes with identical multiindexed columns append and sort
   along time axis
3. Dataframes with different multiindexed columns concatenate along
   column axis (axis=1)

I know that by default the `pandas.concat(objs, axis=1) combines the columns and sorts the row index but I also would like dataframes with identical labels and levels to be joined a long the time axis instead of having them completely side by side.

I should also mention that the dataframes with the same labels and levels are over different time periods that connect with one another but do not overlap.

As an example:

```
first,second,third = rand(5,2),rand(5,2),rand(10,2)

a = pd.DataFrame(first, index=pd.DatetimeIndex(start='1990-01-01', periods=5, freq='d'))
a.columns = pd.MultiIndex.from_tuples([('A','a'),('A','b')])

b = pd.DataFrame(second, index=pd.DatetimeIndex(start='1990-01-06', periods=5, freq='d'))
b.columns = pd.MultiIndex.from_tuples([('A','a'),('A','b')])

c = pd.DataFrame(third, index=pd.DatetimeIndex(start='1990-01-01', periods=10, freq='d'))
c.columns = pd.MultiIndex.from_tuples([('B','a'),('B','b')])

pd.concat([a,b,c], axis=1)
```

Gives this:

```
Out[3]:
    A   B
    a   b   a   b   a   b
1990-01-01  0.351481    0.083324    NaN     NaN     0.060026    0.124302
1990-01-02  0.486032    0.742887    NaN     NaN     0.570997    0.633906
1990-01-03  0.145066    0.386665    NaN     NaN     0.166567    0.147794
1990-01-04  0.257831    0.995324    NaN     NaN     0.630652    0.534507
1990-01-05  0.446912    0.374049    NaN     NaN     0.311473    0.727622
1990-01-06  NaN     NaN     0.920003    0.051772    0.731657    0.393296
1990-01-07  NaN     NaN     0.142397    0.837654    0.597090    0.833893
1990-01-08  NaN     NaN     0.506141    0.056407    0.832294    0.222501
1990-01-09  NaN     NaN     0.655442    0.754245    0.802421    0.743875
1990-01-10  NaN     NaN     0.195767    0.880637    0.215509    0.857576
```

Is there an easy way to get this?

```
d = a.append(b)
pd.concat([d,c], axis=1)

Out[4]:
    A   B
    a   b   a   b
1990-01-01  0.351481    0.083324    0.060026    0.124302
1990-01-02  0.486032    0.742887    0.570997    0.633906
1990-01-03  0.145066    0.386665    0.166567    0.147794
1990-01-04  0.257831    0.995324    0.630652    0.534507
1990-01-05  0.446912    0.374049    0.311473    0.727622
1990-01-06  0.920003    0.051772    0.731657    0.393296
1990-01-07  0.142397    0.837654    0.597090    0.833893
1990-01-08  0.506141    0.056407    0.832294    0.222501
1990-01-09  0.655442    0.754245    0.802421    0.743875
1990-01-10  0.195767    0.880637    0.215509    0.857576
```

The key here is that I don't know how the dataframes will be ordered in the list I basically need something that knows when to concat(obj, axis=1) or concat(obj, axis=0) and can do this to combine my list of dataframes. Maybe there is something already in pandas that can do this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'm not sure there is a one line way to do this (there may be)...
This is one time I would consider creating an empty frame and then filling it:

```
In [11]: frames = [a, b, c]
```

Get the union of their index and columns:

```
In [12]: index = sum(x.index for x in frames)
         cols = sum(x.columns for x in frames)

In [13]: res = pd.DataFrame(index=index, columns=cols)
```

Fill this in with each frame (by label):

```
In [14]: for df in [a, b, c]:
             res.loc[df.index, df.columns] = df

In [15]: res
Out[15]:
                     A                     B
                     a           b         a         b
1990-01-01   0.8516285   0.4087078  0.577000  0.595293
1990-01-02   0.6544393   0.4377864  0.851378  0.595919
1990-01-03   0.3123428  0.03825423  0.834704  0.989195
1990-01-04   0.2314499   0.4971448  0.343455  0.770400
1990-01-05   0.1982945   0.9031414  0.466225  0.463490
1990-01-06   0.7370323   0.3923151  0.263120  0.892815
1990-01-07  0.09038236   0.8778266  0.643816  0.049769
1990-01-08   0.7199705  0.02114493  0.766267  0.472471
1990-01-09  0.06733081    0.443561  0.984558  0.443647
1990-01-10   0.4695022   0.5648693  0.870240  0.949072
```

Comment: Ahh great idea! Obviously not extremely fast but that's not really the point here.